# Does Backbone use etags?

Tags: backbone.js, etag

Does Backbone use etags when fetching changes from server ?
I mean, let's say that when the initial data is loaded, it saves their etags, then when it tries to fetch changes from server, does it send the etags in the header so it will not need to download the data that is up to date ?

I hope I was clear !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone uses jQuery to do ajax requests.  jQuery calls the native browser APIs.  The browser APIs respect etags.

Comment: Thanks, short and exactly what I expected ! =)